# Como sacar valores del json de una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tengo un problema en sacar valores de un una tabla que viene valores de una columna json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo he podido sacar de uno cada uno pero quisiera sacar todos los registros.

```
DECLARE @array NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @array = (select TC001HJSON from #temp1) 

SELECT --*,orderlines.HGENPER
       orders.HFECPRO,orders.HPAIS,orders.htipdoc,orders.hnumdoc,orderlines.HGENPER
        from openjson(@array)  
        with (  
        hfecpro varchar(20) '$.hfecpro',  
        hpais smallint '$.hpais' ,
        htipdoc INT '$.htipdoc' ,
        hnumdoc INT '$.hnumdoc' ,
        cartera nvarchar(max) '$.cartera' AS JSON,
        pasivo nvarchar(max) '$.pasivo' AS JSON
        )  orders
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(orders.pasivo) WITH (HGENPER varchar(500) '$.HGENPER') orderlines

 [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la solución fue esta

```
SELECT   j.hfecpro,j.hpais,j.hnumdoc,
          orderlines.HGENPER,
          orderlines.HUBIGEO,
          orderlines.HFECNAC  ,
          orderlines.HDESCLI  ,
          orderlines.HTIPPER  
FROM @parts t 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.TC001HJSON) WITH (
   hfecpro date '$.hfecpro',
   hpais int '$.hpais',
   hnumdoc varchar(250)'$.hnumdoc' ,
   pasivo nvarchar(max) '$.cartera' AS JSON
) j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.pasivo) WITH (
HGENPER varchar(500) '$.HGENPER',
HUBIGEO varchar(250) '$.HUBIGEO' ,
HFECNAC DATE '$.HFECNAC' ,
HDESCLI VARCHAR(250) '$.HDESCLI' ,
HTIPPER VARCHAR(250) '$.HTIPPER'
) orderlines
```